# Indexing lattice nodes based on distance to lattice center

Tags: number-theory, circles, spheres, integer-lattices

Let's say there is a uniform 3D lattice of length S, where S is an odd number, and the lattice is centered at the origin. Each node has an index, but the twist is that each increment of the index must point to the node that has >= distance to the origin from the previous index.

Comment: If we reduce to 2D, and imagine the construct of some number of circles that include all nodes of the lattice. Each circle will have 2 variables 'a' and 'r', 'a' is the number of integer coordinates it touches, and 'r' is it's radius.

Comment: The issue is that we don't actually know the circles, we don't know 'a' or 'r'. If we knew the circles, we could go through each of them until the sum of their 'a' are >= index - 1 which means we are now on the right circle, then we can calculate the correct integer coordinate.

Comment: By know I mean formulated, I know the first 11 circles, but I haven't been able to find any patterns. Biggest 'a' is 12 at the circle with r √50.

Comment: It also seems like there can only be a certain number of unique circles with respect to 'a,' but infinite with respect to 'r.'

Comment: If we reduce to 1D, we have a line of nodes, index 0 would still be the origin, 1 at <1>, 2 at <-1>, 3 at <2>, 4 at <-2>, etc. This reduces the 'a' of all circles to 2.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that all the correct r values are square roots of whole numbers, which makes sense because a circle touching a coordinate has r = √(xx + yy).

Comment: The a seems to generally increase as r increases, the a values so far, 4, 8, 12, 16.

Comment: If we imagine a polygon constructed with the a values of a circle, we find many shapes, mostly squares and angled by 45° squares, these two shapes always alternate and never repeat, unless there is a different shape in between. The first few different shape are octagon like shapes, but the 6th one is a dodecagon like shape. By "like shape" I mean their angles aren't equal all around the shape.